# What graph to use when there are multiple parameters SSRS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, graph, bar-chart

I want to display number of males and females based on their working hours per week but I am stuck in choosing what kind of graph to use. Below seems like a sloppy graph to display the data:

[image: Graph[1]]

Can you please suggest and recommend any graphs to use or how better to display the figures.

Answer (score 0):

How about different colors for male female and shades for the year?

You'd probably need to create a legend in Paint and add it under .

[image]